# Storing javascript code insde the form

Tags: javascript, django

I need to create form dynamically from Django and I need a script to perform user confirmation before submitting. Can I store the script tags inside the form? or is it better to paste script after the form body? And is there any ideas of performing javascript confirmation of form submitting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form onsubmit="return confirm('do you really want to submit?');"></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Form Media](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/media/), if you'll need something more complicated.

```
form.js:
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#form_id').submit(function() {
          return confirm('do you really want to submit?');
     });
});

forms.py:
class YourForm(forms.Form):
    class Media:
        js = ('form.js',)

template.html:
{{ form.media }}
```

Comment: that's pretty awesome! thanx